# Exporting Vue and Vuex in one custom npm package

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuex

I am trying to break out a Vue/Vuex project into an npm package hosted privately. I think I am getting there however I am unsure of my current layout, so far I have:

```
src/
├── BrokerProposal
│   ├── FormInputs
│   ├── index.js
│   └── modals
└── store
    ├── index.js
    └── modules
        └── proposal
            ├── actions
            ├── getters
            ├── helpers
            ├── mutations
            └── states
                └── validations
```

My aim is to make the BrokerProposal directory importable which is done via the first `index.js` file:

```
const BrokerProposal = require('./BrokerCalculator.vue');

function install(Vue) {
    if (install.installed) return;
    install.installed = true;
    Vue.component("v-broker-proposal", BrokerProposal);
  }
  
const plugin = {
    install
};

let GlobalVue = null;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    GlobalVue = window.Vue;
} else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
    GlobalVue = global.vue;
}
if (GlobalVue) {
    GlobalVue.use(plugin);
}

BrokerProposal.install = install;

export default BrokerProposal;
```

This project also uses vuex so I have broken out the mutators etc of the state into this package to go along with the BrokerProposal, the end user can then bind this store once importing, here is the index.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

// Vuex Modules
import tabs from './modules/tabs'
import proposal from './modules/proposal'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    tabs,
    proposal,
  },
})

export default store
```

I feel like I should be including another index.js file in on the same level as `/src` as there is a section 'main' in the package.json file that must point to something?

Comment: "I feel like I should be including another index.js file in on the same level as /src" - yes. You should avoid side effects like `Vue.use(Vuex)` and `GlobalVue.use(plugin)` that may interfere with a project that uses this package

Comment: @EstusFlask My only confusion is how do I export both the vue component and the state from that one parent level index.js file?

Comment: They are reexported as named exports. You can see how it works in third-party Vue libs, especially the ones with multiple components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side effects like `Vue.use(Vuex)` and `GlobalVue.use(plugin)` should be avoided because they may interfere with a project that consumes this package. It's the responsibility of a project to set up plugins with appropriate Vue instance.

All public exports can be named exports in entry point, e.g. `src/index.js`:

```
export { default as BrokerProposal } from './BrokerProposal';
export { default as store } from './store';
```

Also it's a good practice to export components, in case they need to be imported locally instead of relying on global registration with `Vue.component`.

Comment: I see what you mean, would this scenario require a webpack.config.js file also?

Comment: Depends on your setup. If you already use Vue CLI, you may continue using it, and it doesn't need a separate file for Webpack config. Be aware that Vue CLI produces UMD bundles so it may have problems with tree shaking